# Java: using methods from a class that has implemented methods

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I have a class that has this particular method (manages an array) implemented from a particular interface:

```
public class ArraySort implements sortAndUnsort {
    public int test(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    public int[] sortInsertion(int[] array) {
        int j;     // the number of items sorted so far
        int key;   // the item to be inserted
        int i;  

        // Start with 1 (not 0)
        for (j = 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            key = array[ j ];

            // Smaller values are moving up
            for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && (array[ i ] < key); i--)
            {
                array[ i+1 ] = array[ i ];
            }

            // Put the key in its proper location
            array[ i+1 ] = key;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to plug in an array from another class with a main method:

```
public class ArraySortTest {
    private static ArraySort jokey;
    private static int[] joke2s;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hey there.");

        int[] joke = {0, 9, 7, 4, 5};
        int[] b = jokey.sortInsertion(joke);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

But I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at ArraySortTest.main(ArraySortTest.java:10)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitly initialize an `Object` field it will default to `null` which is why you are getting a null pointer exception when you try to call sortInsertion. You can statically initialize `jokey` with a new instance of `ArraySort` as follows:

```
public class ArraySortTest {
    private static ArraySort jokey = new ArraySort();
    private static int[] joke2s;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hey there.");

        int[] joke = {0, 9, 7, 4, 5};
        int[] b = jokey.sortInsertion(joke);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```